# Repress "Server Busy ... Switch To/Retry" dialog

Tags: c#, process, inkscape

I'm using Inkscape to convert images from PDF to SVG using the following code:

```
internal static void ConvertImageWithInkscapeToLocation(string baseImagePath, string newImagePath, bool crop = true)
{
    InkscapeAction(string.Format("-f \"{0}\" -l \"{1}\"", baseImagePath, newImagePath));
}

internal static void InkscapeAction(string inkscapeArgs)
{
    Process inkscape = null;

    try
    {
        ProcessStartInfo si = new ProcessStartInfo();
        inkscape            = new Process();

        si.WindowStyle      = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        si.FileName         = inkscapePath; // the path to Inkscape.exe, defined elsewhere
        si.Arguments        = inkscapeArgs;
        si.CreateNoWindow   = true;
        inkscape.StartInfo  = si;

        inkscape.Start();
    }
    finally
    {
        inkscape.WaitForExit();
    }
}
```

It's a fairly straightforward "launch app with arguments, wait for close" set up and it works well; the only problem is that on slower machines, the image conversion process (and presumably the `inkscape.WaitForExit()`) takes too long and this dialog message is displayed:

[image: Server Busy Dialog Box]

Clicking on "Switch to..." pops up the Windows Start Menu (I'm guessing because I'm hiding the process); "Retry" will bring the message back up over and over again until the process finishes.  **Is it possible to entirely repress the message box, and automatically retry until it goes through?  Can I at least extend the timeout before the message is displayed?**

Comment: You should probably do this in a background thread and display a "working..." dialog to the user if the process takes too long. (I'm guessing things are being held up because the UI thread is being blocked)

Comment: Help! Help! I'm being repressed!

Comment: @lc. That seems like a very likely conclusion.  Unfortunately, this is tied up in a pretty massive project, and going async (although a goal) is not really possible right now.  Unless I'm misunderstanding you, is it possible to put it in another thread and still have the call go through synchronously?

Comment: @bdimag I don't think swallows (African or otherwise) are going to help me this time...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some ways to do it:

1-A dirty cheap way is to wait with a timeout (WaitForExit(timeout)), do a DoEvents (I assume you are doing it in a winforms app in the main thread), check if process finished and loop until it:

```
finally
{
    while(!inkScape.HasExited)
    {
        inkscape.WaitForExit(500);
        Application.DoEvents();
    }

}
```

2-The right way is to do it in another thread and then signal your main program to continue

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((state) => { ConvertImageWithInkscapeToLocation...  });
```

If you do it in another thread remember CrossThreadException, don't update the UI from the thread.

Comment: Was missing the timeout XD

Comment: Solution 1 - Wonderfully brutal.  I think i'm going to need a shower after this.
Solution 2 - Certainly what I'll be doing after I get out of the shower.

Comment: Question:  Am I going to be melting processors if I set the WaitForExit very low?

Comment: Those are old tricks we used to do in VB 5-6 because we had no thread support, old-school techniques (and dirty ones) ;)

Comment: How much is "very low"? you can't lower it below 1, a DoEvents per millisec is like nothing to actual processors, but you will waste a bit of processor power (maybe a 0.1/0.2%?)

Comment: Eh, it depends on testing.  On the one hand this is run 4-500 times at once, so the half seconds add up.  On the other hand this is something that users will be running on their lunch breaks so the time spent won't be missed or wasted.  Thanks!

Comment: Nope, you will not add nothing, if when you call WaitForExit(500) the process already finished or finishes in less than 500ms the function will exit

Comment: Nifty, reading up on DoEvents, now.  Thanks for all of your time.